# How to draw a line in javaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I am a beginner at javaFX and  started today i think so i want how to draw line and when i make a new group and put a line object it gives me an error like:

```
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import javafx.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public class DrawingLine extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch();

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage){

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        Button btn = new Button();
        Line line = new Line(); //error
        //Line2D line = new Line2D(); error
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();

    }

}
```

then it said to import javax.sound.sampled but it says that I change it to Line2D and this is not in javafx and gives me an error: "can not instantiate
the type Line2D"

Why can't it create a `Line2D`?

Comment: Wecome to StackOverflow. Not sure what, exactly, you're asking. Right now you show only a single line of code, with no context about what `line` is, and you haven't shown the error. As written, it's unclear what you're asking. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Did you even try to search for this? There are many examples on how to draw a line in JavaFX.

Comment: You cannot even find the correct class name for `Line` yourself? It's [`javafx.scene.shape.Line`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Line.html) and you don't import it which is the cause of the error...

Comment: `Line2D` is from AWT, not JavaFX. You want the `Line` class that fabian posted.

Comment: "*eclipse is not prepared for javafx*" What? It is very much so. You just imported the wrong class, it's not Eclipse's fault.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Line` class like this:

```
Line line = new Line(100, 10, 10, 110);
```

You need to specify starting and ending coordinates; this line goes from `(100, 10)` to `(10, 100)`.